# Accept an string if the pattern has the same count value Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that prints if a string is accepted or not under the condition that the number of times a pattern appears in the sequence has the same count value; for example: 'aaabbbccc' would be accepted but not 'aabccc'. I have some ideas of how to implement it, but I'm stuck. Any advice would be helpful, thanks a lot

```
# B = {a^n b^n c^n | n ≥ 0}

string = 'aaabbbccc'

count_a = 0
count_b = 0
count_c = 0

for i in string:
    if i == 'a':
        count_a += 1
    elif i == 'b':
        count_b += 1
    elif i == 'c':
        count_c += 1
    else:
        pass
    
if count_a == count_b and count_b == count_c:
    print('String accepted')
else:
    print('Not accepted')
```

Comment: you do `prev_symbol = i` and then do `if prev_symbol == i`. Why do the check?  Under what condition would the `if` test ever not be `True`? - Also, I'm guessing that you want to reset `count` to zero in there somewhere.  And if you only print `count` once, at the end, what do you expect that to represent?  At best, it's going to tell you what happened at the end of the input string.  In this case, the answer would be `1` because `g` appears just once at the end of the string.

Comment: How are you specifying the element to be counted?  For example, your expected result of 3 would be true for "a" but it would not be true for "b".

Comment: what is the problem with the code after the edit? it seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to accept the language `B = {a^n b^n c^n | n ≥ 0}`. A concise method of checking this is:

```
def accept_b(s):
    n = len(s) - len(s.lstrip('a'))
    return len(s) == 3*n and s[n:2*n] == 'b'*n and s[2*n:] == 'c'*n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
test_str = "aabbccc"
counter = Counter(test_str)
print(len(set(counter.values())) == 1)
```

so the Counter counts the amount of times each char is repeated and then we check
how many different values are inside the dictionary. if they are all the same then the length is 1.

Comment: Now try `xyz` or `bac`. Are they of the form `a^nb^nc^n`?

Comment: @orlp I assumed that the input only contains those chars. else you can replace them all with "" and continue. I also saw your solution, you use slicing which is extremely slow and consumes extra memory and time so stay focused on your own solution bud..

Answer (score 0):

Just count each unique characters in the string and if character count is not equal then return "Not accepted" else "String Accepted"

```
 def character_counter(string):
    set_string = set(string)
    current_count = 0
    for char in set_string:
        if current_count == 0:
            current_count = string.count(char)
        else:
            count_char = string.count(char)
            if count_char!=current_count:
                return 'Not accepted'
    return 'String accepted'
```